# What was Newton's proof of the Product Rule and why was it "not satisfactory"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, math-history

Piermont ([1928](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-34/issue-1/Mathematical-rigor-past-and-present/bams/1183492538.pdf)) :

> As is well known, the proof that Newton gave in his *Principia* that $(uv)' = uv'+vu'$ is not satisfactory.

What was Newton's proof of the **Product Rule** and why was it "not satisfactory" ?

Comment: This might be a question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Explained in https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/02%3A_Calculus_in_the_17th_and_18th_Centuries/2.01%3A_Newton_and_Leibniz_Get_Started, Both, Leibniz and Newton relied on very symmetrical constructions of the limit, that reproduced kown results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**While Leibniz gave Proof 1 , Newton gave Proof 2.**

### Summarized Proof 1 :

Consider the rectangle of sides $u$ & $v$. Area is $A=uv$. Increment both to get new Area $(u+du)(v+dv)$. Expand that & ignore $du \times dv$ which is "infinitely" smaller than the other "infinitesimals"
Hence , we get the Profuct rule $d(uv)=udv+vdu$

### Summarized Proof 2 :

Consider the Area of the rectangle $A=uv$.
Increment both by "half infinitesimals" , $du/2$ & $dv/2$ to get $A+da/2$.
Decrement both by "half infinitesimals" , $du/2$ & $dv/2$ to get $A-da/2$.
Subtract the two to get $da/2+da/2=da$  , which will give the Product rule.

While Proof 1 works in general , Proof 2 works only when we take "half infinitesimals" : **It is a great coincidence !!** If we have incremented by $1/3$ & decremented by $2/3$ , it will not work.

**Thus Proof 2 is not really a Proof : though it gives a good intuition , it is not rigorous & hence it is "not satisfactory" here.**

reference :
https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/02%3A_Calculus_in_the_17th_and_18th_Centuries/2.01%3A_Newton_and_Leibniz_Get_Started

Comment: Just from reading this, it didn’t become clear to me that the point here is that for the particular choice in proof 2 the $du\,dv$ terms cancel. The answer seems to suggest that proof 1 is more satisfactory than proof 2. I don’t think that the source makes this claim, and I would not agree with it.

Comment: Leibniz unjustifiably "ignores" the term & Newton wants to show that the term will automatically "vanish" , though it is not really "vanishing" , except by coincidence , @CarstenS , Opinion : "ignoring" & being clear about it is "better" than pretending that it "vanishes" here !

Answer (score 3):

This answer just adds the original text and translation.

*Principia* ([3e, 1726, p. 244](https://books.google.com/books?id=IOyuEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA244)):

> *Cas.* 1. Rectangulum quodvis motu perpetuo auctum $AB$, ubi de lateribus $A$ & $B$ deerant momentorum dimidia $\frac 1 2 a$ & $\frac 1 2 b$, fuit $A - \frac 1 2 a$ in $B - \frac 1 2 b$, seu $AB - \frac 1 2 aB - \frac 1 2 bA + \frac 1 4 ab$; & quam primum latera $A$ & $B$ alteris momentorum dimidiis aucta sunt, evadit $A + \frac 1 2 a$ in $B + \frac 1 2 b$ seu $AB + \frac 1 2 aB + \frac 1 2 bA + \frac 1 4 ab$. De hoc rectangulo subducatur rectangulum prius, & manebit excessus $aB + bA$. Igitur laterum incrementis totis $a$ & $b$ generatur rectanguli incrementum $aB + bA$. Q.E.D.

Translation ([1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=kmglDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA648)):

> CASE 1. Any rectangle $AB$ increased by continual motion, when the halves of the moments, $\frac 1 2 a$ and $\frac 1 2 b$, were lacking from the sides $A$ and $B$, was $A - \frac 1 2 a$ multiplied by $B - \frac 1 2 b$, or $AB - \frac 1 2 aB - \frac 1 2 bA + \frac 1 4 ab$, and as soon as the sides $A$ and $B$ have been increased by the other halves of the moments, it comes out $A + \frac 1 2 a$ multiplied by $B + \frac 1 2 b$, or $AB + \frac 1 2 aB + \frac 1 2 bA + \frac 1 4 ab$. Subtract the former rectangle from this rectangle, and there will remain the excess $aB + bA$. Therefore by the total increments $a$ and $b$ of the sides there is generated the increment $aB$ + $bA$ of the rectangle. Q.E.D.

Comment: This was ok for Newton. But this review helps only if we know the today's doctrine. The question of the OP is _why is it "not satisfactory"_ any more today? Likewise the Bohr model I was once taught, today it is i) wrong and ii) we should know better. Same here.